# How do I move the mini map to the right side?

Tags: dota-2

Title says it all. I am a League veteran player, and the map is on the right. Making it left when i play dota and right when playing LoL will make it hard for me to follow up on the map

Answer (score 8):

In the game options, check the "Show Minimap on the Right" setting in the Minimap section.